# javascript, object, passing function as arguments with arguments- angular, jquery concept basic misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object, angularjs

I am trying to understand what i am really doing, since i feel i am lack of something. Could you please point me somewhere or confirm my mis/understanding?

```
request.then(function(response) {
        updateCurrentUser(response.data.data);
        currentUser.isAuthenticated();
      });
```

Is basically this?

```
request = {
    then : function (foo){
        foo("first")
    } }

request.then(function (response) { console.log(response) ; });
```

If you see full code [here](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/common/services/authentication/authentication.js)#35 and [here](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/app/login/login.js)#63

directive:

```
    AuthenticationService.login($scope.user.email, $scope.user.password).then(function(loggedIn) {
      if ( !loggedIn ) {
        $scope.authError = "Login failed.  Please check your credentials and try again.";
      }
    });
```

AuthenticationService as factory:

```
login: function(email, password) {
  var request = $http.post('http://', {email: email, password: password});
  return request.then(function(response) {
    updateCurrentUser(response.data.data);
    return currentUser.isAuthenticated();
  });

},
```

The thing i don't understand is how come that the value of loggedIn variable **is equal to the value** what statement return currentUser.isAuthenticated(); returning **AND NOT equal to the** then(function(response) of original as i am returning promise from AuthenticationService.
And how this could be accomplished regarding to the examples above?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what it is that you're asking here.

Comment: i will try to reformulate, thank you

Comment: Are you asking how a variable `foo` can be passed to `.then(function(foo) {`? For such functionality you'll need a little more advanced function: http://jsfiddle.net/XaYXY/.

Comment: hmm..not. In request.then(function(response) .. in response have lets say value "A". Then i return that request and do again request.then(function(loggedIn) and now in loggedIn have value "B" ..regarding to the what currentUser.isAuthenticated() returning...how come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem with conception arises from the fact that you overlooked the **return** statement. What `AuthenticationService.login` does is actually a closure with predefined request, so you can imagine that `login` is replaced with its return value `request.then(function(response) {...`. Then you can simply deduce that entire code row is:

```
AuthenticationService.login($scope.user.email, $scope.user.password).then(
function(response)
{
    updateCurrentUser(response.data.data);
    return currentUser.isAuthenticated();
}).then(
function(loggedIn)
{
  ...
```

This way you may see that result from response should occur as input for the next step with login check.

Comment: heck, yeah maybe .. but i still don't get it this way. Could you please be more verbose?

Comment: hell, yeah i got it : `Because calling then api of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises: ` and following works: `$http.get('http://').then(function(greet) {  
    console.log(greet);
    return "something else"
    }).then(function(greet2){console.log(greet2);});`